# Is it possible to upgrade PostgreSQL 9.2 directlly to Postgres 11.1 over CentOs 7 + cPanel?

Tags: postgresql

I need PostgreSQL 11.1, but my CentOs 7 + cPanel shows:

```
[root@hwsrv-359572 csf]# postgres --version;postmaster --version;
postgres (PostgreSQL) 9.2.24
postgres (PostgreSQL) 9.2.24
[root@hwsrv-359572 csf]#
```

I can UPGRADE from 9.2 to 11.1?

Are the differences between 9.2 and 11.1 very, very big and is it required to install PostgreSQL 11.1 completely?

Maybe some links symbolics is sufficient?
by example 9.2 use:

```
/var/lib/pgsql/data
```

but from version 10.x PgSQL use:

```
/var/lib/pgsql/{version}/data
```

is very hard/impossible
do upgrade from 9.2 to 11.1
and then no lost the GUI of cPanel + PhpPgAdmin?

is best do a installation fresh of Postgres 11.1?

when I do this,
cPanel does not detect Postgres and more:
GUI PhpPgAdmin interface is lost in cPanel.

I believe the best option is to upgrade,
because cPanel includes only Postgres 9.2

However, I can't find how to upgrade from 9.2 to 11.1

Comment: No, you need to do a complete install of Postgres 11, then dump and reload the old database into the new installation or use `pg_upgrade`

Comment: Ouch!, upgrade no is possible now is clear to me, thanks. Maybe can you sayme how I can integrate PgSQL11.1 with cPanel? I install but forever in any point some is breaked. Thanks

Comment: As I said, you can use `pg_upgrade` to migrate the old data directory to the new version.

Comment: with "pg_upgrade" I can read OLD data in NEW version, but some idea about how I can use the GUI (cPanel + PhpPgAdmin) with PostgreSQL 11.1 ?